# Ruby each on nested array returns inconsistent results

Tags: arrays, ruby

We have array of arrays: `matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0, 3, 3]]`

Now, calling

```
matrix.each do |x| 
  print x
end
```

returns the three arrays as I would expect (`[0, 1, 1, 2][0, 5, 0, 0][2, 0, 3, 3]`).

But when doing

```
matrix.each do |x| 
    if x.include?(0)
        z_index = x.index(0)
        for zero in z_index
            for x in matrix do
                matrix[i].delete_at(zero)
                i+=1
            end
        end
    else
        next
    end
end
```

I get `undefined method 'each' for 0:Integer`, which means `each` is picking up the 0 in the first nested array, instead of picking up the entire first nested array. Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: No way. The error is induced.

Comment: Show `#do something here code` it has `each` loop

Comment: Added the full code. There are two more iterations, but they are for loops, not each.

Comment: `for zero in z_index` is the issue. `z_index` is obviously `0` there. FYI: _any_ iteration uses `each` under the hood in ruby. Also, we don’t use `for` loops in ruby, it’s considered a code smell.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ you shouldn’t delete elements from the currently iterated array.

Comment: Note that `i` is not initialized. Perhaps you meant `x`. btw, wean yourself from using `for` as soon as possible. Most Rubiests don't use it, many have never used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
for zero in z_index
```

This is effectively

```
z_index.each do |zero|
```

The `in` part of a `for in` loop has to be something you can iterate over (an array)

`z_index` is the first element of `x` which is the first element of `matrix` so it contains an integer.

Comment: Right! I was expecting each to grab the elements regardless of the number (1 or 100). Why doesn't that work? What's the alternative if in the next loop there is more than 1 element in the array?

Comment: If you want to iterate over the elements, maybe what you wanted to do was `for zero in x` but can you explain what you expect the code to do? I don't see `i` is initialized before use, by the way, so that'  going to be a problem further on.

Comment: Yes, I didn't paste the whole method here. z_index can have 1 or multiple elements. In the case of 1 element I run into the mentioned error. Is there a neat way of handling 1 element scenario? Or should I just go with if else statement?

Comment: `z_index` CANNOT have one or multiple elements, it can only have `nil` (if there's no element `0`) or it can have the index of the first occurence of `0`, which in your examples happens to be `0`.  If you want an array of all the index positions of `0` you should do `z_index = x.each_with_index.map{|x,i| x.zero? ? i : nil}.compact`